# is there a better alternative to gps position tracking?

Tags: android, gps, position, tracking

After doing some asking around and reading, it sounds like you're lucky to get even within 10 meters of accuracy with a GPS on a mobile device (specifically Android).
I've seen a video that shows a home-made device reading out to several decimals. Is this only because of the data format from the chip? (aka, not really precise either?)
Is there any real working way that I can use an Android device to track real static positions within rooms in a building?
Ideally, I'd be able to mark a point in a room and come back to it later with virtually no drift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LocationProvider is different from each Android Device you are using. The SDK does not handle the calculation of your exact location but the phone does. But each device can have one or mare LocationProvider, thats why you need to set some Criterias when your picking a LocationProvider.

To get your exact position on the earth the GPS needs 3 points from 3 different satellites. Thats why the GPS works best in the open space. Regarding making a precise calculation on a static persion inside a building, this conflict with the whole scenario of the GPS-System. I'm not saying it's impossible to get a location inside a building but as with any other signals, obstacles that blocks the signal makes is weaker.

If you are inside a barn with thin walls this might work, but inside a 10 storage building your scenario seems quite impossible.

You can though force your phone to get the best LocationProvider and hopefully that will give you the most precise location. And yes, you can get inside 1-2m in precision outside.

I hope this helps a little. Enjoy your project.